# Facebook Messenger Plugin Reference giving error 500

Tags: facebook, messenger

I'm testing the facebook messenger plugin (published in F8) in my web site, according to the documentation  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference I just need to include the JS SDK and the plugin code with my app_id and page_id, but I'm getting an error 500 on console.

```html
<body>
 <script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : 'my_app_ID',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.6'
     });
   };

   (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
 </script>

    <div class="fb-messengermessageus"
  messenger_app_id="my_app_ID"
  page_id="my_page_ID"
  color="blue"
  size="small" ></div>
```

An Iframe is inyected into my DOM by it's empty.

Has anyone got the same error? someone has done it successfully?

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: Can you add more details at what stage you are getting the 500 error? Do you have a URL to share we can try it out at?